# How to make a sprite node move with a swipe

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a SKSpriteNode called `greyCircle` and I am trying to make it move according to where it is swiped. Right now it moves this way:

```
func touchMoved(toPoint pos : CGPoint) {
   greyCircle?.run(SKAction.move(to: pos, duration: 0.5))
}
```

The problem with this is that it basically just moves to where the touch is, rather than reacting to the finger swipe and moving accordingly.

Comment: The easiest way is to implement gesture recognizer on a view. Search for that. But remeber, the recognizer is not added to a scene, but rather to the view.

Comment: Would this go to any direction that is swiped or just right, left, up, or down?   Thanks

Comment: You are implementing a recognizer to detect in which direction user has swiped. Based on that, you move your node accordingly.

Comment: @SilasLenihan Does your circle needs to have a specific velocity once the swipe occurs? Should the swipe only be handled when the touch originated within the circle's bound? Should touches originating outside the circle's bound not be handled?

Comment: @Francis.Beauchamp My idea is to basically have it so that you originate the touch anywhere and then once the swipe comes into contact with the circle the circle moves accordingly based on the angle of the swipe and the velocity of the swipe. I actually got the angle down by using some trigonometry functions and changing the .zRotation of `greyCircle`. What I'm left with is figuring out how to make it move when the swipe comes into contact with the circle, and finding the appropriate velocity for that action. Thanks

Comment: @Whirlwind oh okay that seems much simpler than what I came up with, thanks.